# AWS CDK CfnMaintenanceWindowTask/taskInvocationParameters - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-ssm

I am using AWS CDK, library @aws-cdk/aws-ssm and TypeScript to create CfnMaintenanceWindowTask. I am using as an example code from [AWS docs for cfn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-maintenancewindowtask.html#cfn-ssm-maintenancewindowtask-taskinvocationparameters), example for "**Create a Run Command task that targets instances using a maintenance window target ID**". Example of the JSON cfn code which I am trying to transform to CDK.

```
"TaskInvocationParameters": {
                "MaintenanceWindowRunCommandParameters": {
                    "Parameters": {
                        "Operation": [
                            "Install"
                        ],
                        "RebootOption": [
                            "NoReboot"
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

In the CfnMaintenanceWindowTask object I want to define property **taskInvocationParameters** using TypeScript code down below.
**The problem is that I am not allowed to do it because of the following error for the property taskInvocationParameters:**

"*TS2322: Type '{ maintenanceWindowRunCommandParameters: { Parameters: { Operation: string[]; BaselineTags: { key: string; values: string[]; }[]; RebootOption: string[]; }[]; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IResolvable | TaskInvocationParametersProperty | undefined'.*"

My implementation is probably wrong but **I am not able to see where the issue could be.**

```
const maintenanceWindowRunCommandParametersWindowsParametersBaselineTags = {
            key: 'PatchBaseline',
            values: [
                'Windows-Server-CritImp-7app-CDK'
            ]
        };    

const maintenanceWindowRunCommandParametersWindowsParameters = {
            Operation: [
                'Install'
            ],
            BaselineTags:[
                maintenanceWindowRunCommandParametersWindowsParametersBaselineTags
            ],
            RebootOption: [
                'NoReboot'
            ]
        };

const maintenanceWindowRunCommandParametersWindows = {
            Parameters: [
                maintenanceWindowRunCommandParametersWindowsParameters
            ],
        };    

const taskInvocationParametersRunPatchBaselineAssociationWindows = {
                maintenanceWindowRunCommandParameters: [
                    maintenanceWindowRunCommandParametersWindows
                ]
            };
    
    const maintenanceWindowTaskWindowsServer = new ssm.CfnMaintenanceWindowTask(this, 'Maintenance-task-Windows-CDK',{
                name: 'Maintenance-task-Windows-CDK',
                priority: 0,
                maxConcurrency: '2',
                maxErrors: '2',
                taskType: 'RUN_COMMAND',
                taskArn: 'AWS-RunPatchBaselineAssociation',
                taskInvocationParameters: taskInvocationParametersRunPatchBaselineAssociationWindows,
                windowId: maintenanceWindowEveryDayScanOnly.ref,
                targets: [
                    maintenanceWindowTaskWindowsServersTargets
                ]
            });
```

### UPDATE

I have implemented the code from @Hcaertnit. After deployment I am receiving following error.

> Failed resources:
> 10:42:06 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindowTask   | Maintenance-task-Windows-CDK (MaintenancetaskWindowsCDK) Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
> at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.amazonaws.services.ssm.model.RegisterTaskWithMaintenanceWindowRequest["TaskInvocationParameters"]->com.amazonaws.services.ssm.model.MaintenanceWindowTaskInvoc
> ationParameters["MaintenanceWindowRunCommandParameters"]->com.amazonaws.services.ssm.model.MaintenanceWindowRunCommandParameters["Parameters"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["BaselineTags"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error:

> Failed resources: 10:42:06 | CREATE_FAILED |
> AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindowTask | Maintenance-task-Windows-CDK
> (MaintenancetaskWindowsCDK) Cannot deserialize instance of
> java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: UNKNOWN; line:
> -1, column: -1]

Was caused by inaccurately implemented **BaselineTags** parameter. This parameter is part of **AWS-RunPatchBaselineAssociation** run command. There is following definition for this parameter.

```
"BaselineTags": {
      "type": "String",
      "description": "(Optional) The baseline tags to use during the patching operation.",
      "allowedPattern": "(^$)|^Key=(.){1,256},Values=(.){0,256}[^,]$",
      "default": ""
    },
```

Knowing this, the correct format of code is like this:

```
const maintenanceWindowTaskWindowsServer = new ssm.CfnMaintenanceWindowTask(this, 'Maintenance-task-Windows-CDK',{
            name: 'Maintenance-task-Windows-CDK',
            description: 'Maintenance windows task used for Windows Servers.',
            priority: 0,
            maxConcurrency: '2',
            maxErrors: '2',
            taskType: 'RUN_COMMAND',
            taskArn: 'AWS-RunPatchBaselineAssociation',
            taskInvocationParameters: {
                maintenanceWindowRunCommandParameters: {
                    parameters: {
                        Operation: ["Install"],
                        BaselineTags: ["Key=PatchBaseline,Values=Windows-Server-CritImp-7app-CDK"],
                        RebootOption: ["NoReboot"]
                    }
                }
            },
            windowId: maintenanceWindowEveryDayScanOnly.ref,
            targets: [
                {
                    key: 'WindowTargetIds',
                    values: [
                        maintenanceWindowTargetWindowsServer.ref
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge your first 4 variables into one like this:

```js
const taskInvocationParametersRunPatchBaselineAssociationWindows = {
    maintenanceWindowRunCommandParameters: {
        parameters: {
            Operation: ["Install"],
            BaselineTags: [
                {
                    key: "PatchBaseline",
                    values: ["Windows-Server-CritImp-7app-CDK"],
                }
            ],
            RebootOption: ["NoReboot"],
        },
    },
};
```

1. [`maintenanceWindowRunCommandParameters`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ssm-maintenancewindowtask-taskinvocationparameters.html#cfn-ssm-maintenancewindowtask-taskinvocationparameters-maintenancewindowruncommandparameters) takes an *object*; you were passing it an array, and inside that array you were passing the object.
2. That object has a [`parameters`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ssm-maintenancewindowtask-maintenancewindowruncommandparameters.html#cfn-ssm-maintenancewindowtask-maintenancewindowruncommandparameters-parameters) (not actually `Parameters`) property, which is an object; again you passed an array to that property, with the correct object inside.

I combined the variables into one like above, because all the long variable names becomes pretty unmanageable.

Comment: You are right, the code is much more readable and manageable. Although the code looks alright, I am not able to deploy it. I am receiving following error.

Failed resources:
 10:42:06 | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::SSM::MaintenanceWindowTask   | Maintenance-task-Windows-CDK (MaintenancetaskWindowsCDK) Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]

Comment: were you able to deploy the code? I have attached full error code to the thread as an update.